# Retornar Json com os atributos de uma classe sem "_" nas iniciais

Tags: javascript

tenho essa seguinte classe javascript:

```
class Usuario {
  constructor() {
    this._nome = '';
    this._idade = '';
  }


  get nome() {
    return this._nome;
  }

  set nome( value ) {
    this._nome = value;
  }

  get idade() {
    return this._idade;
  }

  set idade( value ) {
    this._idade = value;
  }
}
```

Quando eu retorno ela via `json`, ela me retorna os nomes com `_` no inicio. Sei que esse sinal significa que o atributo só pode ser usado dentro da própria classe, por isso eu gostaria de retornar os nomes dos atributos sem esse caractere.

Comment: Que tal tirar o `_` que é só ruído no nome?

Comment: Mas as boas praticas dizem que é bom encapsular os dados.

Comment: Isso é um completo absurdo. Leia algumas dessas respostas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101+boas+pr%C3%A1ticas Eu tenho uma palestra que fala do mal que as pessoas estão fazendo para os outros e para si próprias com esse negócio de boas práticas.

Comment: Você pode até ter razão, mas a pergunta não é sobre boas praticas.

Comment: Quem argumentou sobre boas práticas foi você, eu só repliquei o que você disse. Eu te dei uma solução mais fácil e correta, eu faria o correto, mas é direito seu não fazê-lo.